# Find value that maximises equation

Tags: calculus

After doing calculations, I have reached the following equation:

$\frac{\sigma^2Tt-\sigma^2t^2}{T} $

I am interested in finding a value of $t$ within $[0,T]$ that maximises this equation.

Substituting in 0, I get 0, but substituting in T also results in 0 so I am not sure on which approach to take here to identify the variable that would maximise the equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$ \frac{\sigma^2 Tt - \sigma^2t^2}{T} = \frac{\sigma^2}{T} (Tt - t^2). $$
The factor $ \frac{\sigma^2}{T}$ (I assume) is constant, so we need only maximize $f(t) := Tt - t^2$.

The Extreme value theorem says that a continuous function $f$ on the interval $[a,b]$ attains its maximum at at least one point in $t\in[a,b]$. Moreover, if this point is not $a$ or $b$, then $f'(t) = 0$.

Differentiating gives $f'(t) = T- 2t$. This is zero only when $ t = T/2$. So $f$ can be maximized only $t \in \{0,T/2,T\}$. We check that $f(0)=f(T)=0$, while $f(T/2) = T^2/4 >0$. So the maximum at attained at $t=T/2$.